# Removing special characters VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm using VBA to read some titles and then copy that information to a PowerPoint presentation.

The problem is that the titles have special characters, but image files that I am also coping over do not.

The title forms part of a path to load a JPEG into a picture container, for example `P k.jpg`, but the title is called `p.k`.

I want to be able to ignore the special characters in the title and just get it to see a space instead so it picks up the right JPG file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What do you consider "special" characters, just simple punctuation?  You should be able to use the `Replace` function: `Replace("p.k","."," ")`.

```
Sub Test()
Dim myString as String
Dim newString as String

myString = "p.k"

newString = replace(myString, ".", " ")

MsgBox newString

End Sub
```

If you have several characters, you can do this in a custom function or a simple chained series of `Replace` functions, etc.

```
  Sub Test()
Dim myString as String
Dim newString as String

myString = "!p.k"

newString = Replace(Replace(myString, ".", " "), "!", " ")

'## OR, if it is easier for you to interpret, you can do two sequential statements:
'newString = replace(myString, ".", " ")
'newString = replace(newString, "!", " ")

MsgBox newString

End Sub
```

If you have a lot of potential special characters (non-English accented ascii for example?) you can do a custom function or iteration over an array.

```
Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?"  'modify as needed
Sub test()
Dim myString as String
Dim newString as String
Dim char as Variant
myString = "!p#*@)k{kdfhouef3829J"
newString = myString
For each char in Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
    newString = Replace(newString, char, " ")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Great post. But it does not work for the character ?

Comment: @JohnAndrews yes it will if you modify the `SpecialCharacters` string so that the question mark is part of it: `Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?"`.

Comment: The only character I would argue is missing from the list is the comma itself! But I know that it would take some extra tinkering to adjust for that char

Comment: To also remove commas, replace first line with `Const SpecialCharacters As String = "! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) { [ ] } ? ,"` and in the for statement `For each char in Split(SpecialCharacters, " ")`. You can replace the spaces by any other character in both statements, for example `_`.

Comment: any tip to replace spaces with "_"? I have added a space in the list of characters and for some reason it does not work

Comment: This function replaces each item in the delimited list with a space (`" "`). Please review documentation for the string `Replace` method and you could update as needed; but you'll need some if/then or other conditional block to handle the space replacement, since, by original design, this function replaces ANY specified character with a space, if currently implemented you will end up replacing space with space :)

Answer (score 19):

In the case that you not only want to exclude a list of special characters, but to exclude **all** characters that are not letters or numbers, I would suggest that you use a char type comparison approach.

For each character in the String, I would check if the unicode character is between "A" and "Z", between "a" and "z" or between "0" and "9". This is the vba code:

```
Function cleanString(text As String) As String
    Dim output As String
    Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        c = Mid(text, i, 1) 'Select the character at the i position
        If (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "0" And c <= "9") Or (c >= "A" And c <= "Z") Then
            output = output & c 'add the character to your output.
        Else
            output = output & " " 'add the replacement character (space) to your output
        End If
    Next
    cleanString = output
End Function
```

The [Wikipedia list of Unicode characers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) is a good quick-start if you want to customize this function a little more.

This solution has the advantage to be functionnal even if the user finds a way to introduce new special characters. It also faster than comparing two lists together.

Comment: This is much faster than regex if the number of character in a cell is small. For cell have 20 chars, about 15 times faster. At about 2000 chars, they are about the same, for higher, regex is faster.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how removed special characters.

I simply applied regex

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" 'The regex pattern to find special characters
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "" 'The replacement for the special characters
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 'Initialize the regex object    
Dim GCID As String: GCID = "Text #N/A" 'The text to be stripped of special characters

' Configure the regex object
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

' Perform the regex replacement
GCID = regEx.Replace(GCID, strReplace)
```

Comment: Does not work on OSX.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738332/activex-component-can-t-create-object-excel-for-mac

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use, based on this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/707-excel-replace-accented-characters.html)

```
Function StripAccentb(RA As Range)

Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer
Dim S As String
'Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
'Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
Const AccChars = "ñéúãíçóêôöá" ' using less characters is faster
Const RegChars = "neuaicoeooa"
S = RA.Cells.Text
For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
S = Replace(S, A, B)
'Debug.Print (S)
Next


StripAccentb = S

Exit Function
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=StripAccentb(B2) ' cell address
```

Sub version for all cells in a sheet:

```
Sub replacesub()
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer
Dim S As String
Const AccChars = "ñéúãíçóêôöá" ' using less characters is faster
Const RegChars = "neuaicoeooa"
Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select '
For Each cell In Selection
If cell <> "" Then
S = cell.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
    A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
    B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
    S = replace(S, A, B)
    Next
cell.Value = S
Debug.Print "celltext "; (cell.Text)
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ferroao's long list of characters, I am using this function:

```
Function replaceSpecialCharacters(str)
Dim badCharacters, goodCharacters As Variant
Dim i As Integer
badCharacters = Array("Š", "Ž", "š", "ž", "Ÿ", "À", "Á", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Ç", "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï", "Ð", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ý", "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "ç", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "ÿ")
goodCharacters = Array("S", "Z", "s", "z", "Y", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "E", "E", "E", "E", "I", "I", "I", "I", "D", "N", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "U", "U", "U", "U", "Y", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "e", "e", "e", "e", "I", "I", "I", "I", "d", "n", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "u", "u", "u", "u", "y", "y")

For i = 0 To UBound(badCharacters)
  str = Replace(str, badCharacters(i), goodCharacters(i))
Next i

replaceSpecialCharacters = str

End Function
```

Calling the function from anywhere else with

```
Debug.Print replaceSpecialCharacters("žÃÌý")
```

Or

```
BadString = "žÃÌý"
GoodString =  replaceSpecialCharacters(BadString)
```

Sidenote:
The approach is replacing special characters with the most closest match, like ž with z.

PS:
The OP mentioned a special-character ".", which can be included in both arrays as well, so that the "." is e.g.: replaced with " ".

Comment: Hint: Instead of listing *all* "special characters" you might profit from a match of any given/current character within an alphabetic array `Application.Match(curChar, abc)`; omitting the optional 3rd argument allows to return the *closest* alphabetical value position in an ordered list of letters, i.e. the unaccented base letter ~~> see my post [replace different types of characters with circumflex with their non-circumflex counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75288393/replace-different-types-of-characters-with-circumflex-with-their-non-circumflex/75290419#75290419)