# Save attachments using mail subject in file name

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, filepath, email-attachments

I want to save all attachments from my Outlook 365 inbox.

Copying [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ZXLyT6gqQp4) I wrote:

```vb
Sub Download_Attachments()

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim olFolder_Inbox As Folder
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olAttachment As Attachment

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim File_Saved_Folder As String

    File_Saved_Folder_Path = "C:\GIS\temp\mails"

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set olFolder_Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    For Each olMail In olFolder_Inbox.Items
    
        If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" And olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        
            fso.CreateFolder (fso.BuildPath(File_Saved_Folder_Path, Trim(olMail.Subject)))
            
            For Each olAttachment In olMail.Attachments
            
                olAttachment.SaveAsFile fso.BuildPath(File_Saved_Folder_Path, Trim(olMail.Subject)) & "\" & olAttachment.FileName
                                    
            Next olAttachment
        
        End If

    Next olMail
    
    Set olFolder_Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    
    Set fso = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

When I execute the macro I get roughly (translated from Swedish):

> Error 76, Cant find the path

Comment: I'm assuiming you're getting the error at line  fso.CreateFolder (fso.BuildPath(File_Saved_Folder_Path, Trim(olMail.Subject)))?  If so, make sure your subject does not contain [special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356993/removing-special-characters-vba-excel) (since files cannot have them). Also limit your subject just in case so you don't create a path too big in naming

Answer (score 0):

The `Subject` property of the `MailItem` class and the `FileName` property of the `Attachment` class may contain forbidden symbols that can't be used for filenames. So. before calling the `SaveAsFile` method of the `Attachment` class you need to check the file path whether such folder exists and the path doesn't contain forbidden symbols. See [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more information.