# Replace different types of characters with circumflex with their non-circumflex counterpart

Tags: excel, vba

I have been tasked with rewriting a vba script that replaces circumflex characters in a csv with their normal counterparts. The current script just uses a bunch of replace functions for every character.
This is the current script:

```
'i is the current row, this whole thing sits in a loop to loop through all rows in the csv 

            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Á", "A")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Á", "A")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Á", "A")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Á", "A")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "À", "A")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "À", "A")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "À", "A")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "À", "A")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Â", "A")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Â", "A")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Â", "A")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Â", "A")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Å", "A")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Å", "A")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Å", "A")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Å", "A")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ã", "A")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ã", "A")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ã", "A")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ã", "A")
                        
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "à", "a")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "à", "a")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "à", "a")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "à", "a")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "á", "a")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "á", "a")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "á", "a")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "á", "a")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "â", "a")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "â", "a")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "â", "a")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "â", "a")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "å", "a")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "å", "a")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "å", "a")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "å", "a")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ã", "a")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ã", "a")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ã", "a")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ã", "a")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "É", "E")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "É", "E")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "É", "E")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "É", "E")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "È", "E")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "È", "E")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "È", "E")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "È", "E")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ê", "E")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ê", "E")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ê", "E")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ê", "E")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "é", "e")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "é", "e")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "é", "e")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "é", "e")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "è", "e")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "è", "e")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "è", "e")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "è", "e")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ê", "e")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ê", "e")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ê", "e")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ê", "e")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Í", "I")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Í", "I")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Í", "I")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Í", "I")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ì", "I")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ì", "I")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ì", "I")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ì", "I")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Î", "I")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Î", "I")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Î", "I")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Î", "I")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "í", "i")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "í", "i")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "í", "i")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "í", "i")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ì", "i")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ì", "i")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ì", "i")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ì", "i")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "î", "i")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "î", "i")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "î", "i")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "î", "i")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ó", "O")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ó", "O")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ó", "O")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ó", "O")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ò", "O")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ò", "O")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ò", "O")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ò", "O")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ô", "O")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ô", "O")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ô", "O")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ô", "O")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Õ", "O")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Õ", "O")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Õ", "O")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Õ", "O")
                        
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ó", "o")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ó", "o")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ó", "o")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ó", "o")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ò", "o")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ò", "o")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ò", "o")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ò", "o")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ô", "o")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ô", "o")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ô", "o")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ô", "o")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "õ", "o")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "õ", "o")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "õ", "o")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "õ", "o")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ø", "o")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ø", "o")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ø", "o")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ø", "o")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ú", "U")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ú", "U")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ú", "U")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ú", "U")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ù", "U")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ù", "U")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ù", "U")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ù", "U")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Û", "U")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Û", "U")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Û", "U")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Û", "U")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ú", "u")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ú", "u")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ú", "u")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ú", "u")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ù", "u")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ù", "u")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ù", "u")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ù", "u")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "û", "u")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "û", "u")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "û", "u")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "û", "u")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ý", "Y")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ý", "Y")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ý", "Y")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ý", "Y")
                        
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ý", "y")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ý", "y")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ý", "y")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ý", "y")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ç", "C")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ç", "C")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ç", "C")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ç", "C")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ç", "c")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ç", "c")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ç", "c")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ç", "c")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ñ", "N")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ñ", "N")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ñ", "N")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ñ", "N")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "ñ", "n")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "ñ", "n")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "ñ", "n")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "ñ", "n")
            
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "š", "s")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "š", "s")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "š", "s")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "š", "s")
                       
            .Cells(i, 4) = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), "Ã©", "e")
            .Cells(i, 5) = Replace(.Cells(i, 5), "Ã©", "e")
            .Cells(i, 7) = Replace(.Cells(i, 7), "Ã©", "e")
            .Cells(i, 9) = Replace(.Cells(i, 9), "Ã©", "e")
```

I'm looking to rewrite this monstrosity into a easier to read and better to maintain script.

Im aware i can already simplyfie this by using loops and grouping different to-replace-Characters together. But this still doestn really satisfy me, I want to know if theres a better way to go about this that im not seeing.

Comment: [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace)?

Comment: Posted a tricky way to simplify the change to unaccented base characters. @AnnyedSandwich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Return unaccented base characters**

You may profit from a match of a current character within an alphabetic array `Application.Match(curChar, abc)`; omitting the optional 3rd argument allows to return the closest alphabetical value position in an ordered list of letters, i.e. the unaccented **base letter**.

The **match** result `no` (a Variant) shows a valid numeric position number for all alphabetical counterparts, any other symbol checks (thus `Not IsNumeric` or caught by `IsError`) will be used to return the unchanged input character.

Matched letters will be converted to uppercase if the original letter is uppercase.

```
Function unaccented(ByVal txt As String) As String
'1) assign alphabet letters to array
    Dim abc As Variant: abc = [Char(Column(A:Z)+96)]    ' Excel only shortcut!
'2) match base characters in alphabet
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        'get current character
        Dim curChar As String: curChar = Mid(txt, i, 1)
        'get alphabetical base position
        Dim no As Variant:  no = Application.Match(curChar, abc)   ' without 3rd arg 0 !!
        'provide for case sensibility
        If IsNumeric(no) Then
            curChar = IIf(curChar = UCase(curChar), UCase(abc(no)), abc(no))
        End If
        'assemble total string to be returned
        unaccented = unaccented & curChar
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dictionary Object to hold the character mappings and a Regular Expression to do the replacement. It might not be quicker but it should be easier to maintain, just update the arrays ar1 and ar2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertToAscii()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim regex As Object, dict As Object
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
   
    ' character map
    Set dict = BuildCharacterMap()
   
    ' regex
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With
    
    ' worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            Call ChangeChar(.Cells(i, 4), regex, dict)
            Call ChangeChar(.Cells(i, 5), regex, dict)
            Call ChangeChar(.Cells(i, 7), regex, dict)
            Call ChangeChar(.Cells(i, 9), regex, dict)
            .Cells(i, 10) = "X"
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows processed", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
   
End Sub

Sub ChangeChar(cell As Range, ByRef regex, ByRef dict)

    Dim k, s As String
    s = Replace(cell.Value, "Ã©", "e") ' special case
    For Each k In dict.keys
        regex.Pattern = "[" & dict(k) & "]"
        s = regex.Replace(s, k)
    Next
    cell.Value = s

End Sub

Function BuildCharacterMap() As Object

    Dim dict, ar1, ar2, a, v
    ' character mappings
    ar1 = Array("o ø", "C Ç", "s š")
    ar2 = Array("A ÁÀÂÅÃ", "E ÉÈÊ", "I ÍÌÎ", "N Ñ", "O ÓÒÔÕ", "U ÚÙÛ", "Y Ý")

    ' build character map as dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
   
    ' upper and lower cases
    For Each v In ar2
        a = Split(v, " ")
        dict.Add a(0), a(1)
        dict.Add LCase(a(0)), LCase(a(1))
    Next
   
    ' single case
    For Each v In ar1
        a = Split(v, " ")
        If dict.exists(a(0)) Then
            dict(a(0)) = dict(a(0)) & a(1)
        Else
            dict.Add a(0), a(1)
        End If
    Next
    
    Set BuildCharacterMap = dict

End Function
```